# Laravel 8 redirect user to intended page after registration

Tags: redirect, laravel-8, registration

I am trying to redirect the user to intended page after registration.
This is my controller:
What I want ?
User click on bottom(buy) the web redirected the user to register **after register the system should redirect the user to buy page .**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return redirect(session('link'))->with('success', 'Thank you for your previous transaction! Go to your Profile to review your transaction history.');
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {       

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        // $this->middleware('guest')->except('job_list');

     }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->syncRoles([3]);
    return $user;
    }
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        if (session('link')) {
            $myPath     = session('link');
            $registerPath  = url('/register');
            $previous   = url()->previous();
    
            if ($previous = $registerPath) {
                session(['link' => $myPath]);
            }else{
                session(['link' => $previous]);
            }
        } else{
            session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
        }
        return view('auth.register');
    }

 
 


}
```

This is the error  I got :
Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::with does not exist.
So is there away to redirect user to intended page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

I solved this just adding this line